# Can't write image file on actual server

Tags: php, android, json, image, base64

I'm working with android and try to create an app that able to upload several image to the server. I had tried to upload the image to my localhost using xampp, it works well. But when I try to upload to my enterprise server I can't find my file, in the other word. The file can't be written. I don't know what make it failed? This is my code

Upload tp XAMPP

Connection string `private static final String url_photo = "http://192.168.7.110/blabla/base.php";`

Path `static final String path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\psn_asset_oracle\\Images\\";`

Upload to actual enterprise server

Connection String `private static final String url_photo = "http://192.168.4.27/oracle/logam/am/data_images/android_image/base.php";`

Path `static final String path = "http://192.168.4.27/oracle/logam/am/data_images/android_image/";`

My code to upload to server

```
params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name_1",
                        image_name_1));
                params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name_2",
                        image_name_2));
                params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name_3",
                        image_name_3));
                params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name_4",
                        image_name_4));
json_photo = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_photo, "POST", params_p);
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params_p = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST["image_name_1"]) && isset($_POST["image_name_2"]) && isset($_POST["image_name_3"]) && isset($_POST["image_name_4"]) 
&& isset($_POST["image_1"]) && isset($_POST["image_2"]) && isset($_POST["image_3"]) && isset($_POST["image_4"]))
{
$image_name_1 = $_POST["image_name_1"];
$image_name_2 = $_POST["image_name_2"];
$image_name_3 = $_POST["image_name_3"];
$image_name_4 = $_POST["image_name_4"];
$image_1 = $_POST["image_1"];
$image_2 = $_POST["image_2"];
$image_3 = $_POST["image_3"];
$image_4 = $_POST["image_4"];

/*---------base64 decoding utf-8 string-----------*/
$binary_1=base64_decode($image_1);
$binary_2=base64_decode($image_2);
$binary_3=base64_decode($image_3);
$binary_4=base64_decode($image_4);

/*-----------set binary, utf-8 bytes----------*/
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
/*---------------open specified directory and put image on it------------------*/
$file_1 = fopen($image_name_1, 'wb');
$file_2 = fopen($image_name_2, 'wb');
$file_3 = fopen($image_name_3, 'wb');
$file_4 = fopen($image_name_4, 'wb');

/*---------------------assign image to file system-----------------------------*/
fwrite($file_1, $binary_1);
fclose($file_1);
fwrite($file_2, $binary_2);
fclose($file_2);
fwrite($file_3, $binary_3);
fclose($file_3);
fwrite($file_4, $binary_4);
fclose($file_4);

$response["message"] = "Success";
echo json_encode($response);
```

}

I've contact my DBA and asked to give me permission to write the file, and it still doesn't work. The error is json doesn't give "Success" as message that indicate the file failed to be written. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file server allows write access permission? Sample of chmod, http://catcode.com/teachmod/

Is your enterprise server online? The IP address looks private to me, 192.168.4.27.

Comment: Ya my dba tell me that they has change it. Of course it looks private but I'm successfully insert a query from that ip.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use json use http post.

See below code

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String postURL = "your url";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);

    try {
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(img, "image.jpg");
        reqEntity.addPart("image", bab); 
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Here img is your image in ByteArray format

Comment: can you explain me why I need to change to multipart? because I'm able to do it in my local server with xampp.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved after my DBA give me another file path.